# How to get my I-20 back from the Consulate when it was not returned along with my visa?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

My I-20 and passport were taken during my interview. I got my visa approved and collected my passport but not my I-20. When I mailed them regarding this issue, even though my visa was approved, they are saying it's still under administrative processing.

How can I get my I-20 back as it is important for travel?

My travel date is on 22 Dec 2016.

Can you help me in getting my I-20 as quickly as possible?

I also tried contacting the college about the issue. They said as it is with the consulate, that I should collect it from them.

---

My passport was collected and visa was approved but my I-20, that was taken along with my passport during the interview, was not returned. As I need my I-20 to travel, can anyone suggest or guide me how to get my I-20 (my travel date is 23-12-16!) ?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. You received your passport back? Did the consulate place a visa in it?

Comment: Did you get a visa? If you don't know what a visa is, it's a sticker with a photograph placed on a page in your passport. If you didn't get it, unfortunately you've been rejected and won't be able to move to the US for now.

Comment: If you collected your passport, then either you have the visa or you don't. Just check your passport to see if it contains a visa or not.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid the visa isn't terribly useful without a valid I-20.

Comment: Yes , I did get my Visa . I need my I-20

Comment: Hyderabad , will they allow me inside to enquire about my case ??

Answer (score 1):

You can can make an appointment and physically go to the embassy to retrieve your I20. You should not have a problem if you're standing in front of someone and explaining because this is a trivial issue. You're probably getting email responses from some novice at the embassy. If you're unable to receive the I-20 back because it was either lost or something else, so far as your visa is valid you can go the alternative route.

Your school's International Student Services can issue a replacement I-20 or DS-2019 if yours is lost, damaged, or stolen. Reprinted I-20s and DS-2019s are tracked in SEVIS by the Department of Homeland Security, so you should request a replacement only if your I-20 or DS-2019 has been lost, stolen, or damaged.

It takes 7-10 days however you can expedite it if it's very urgent by explaining to your international student services counselor.